# Run test cases in mtm automatically (not coded UI)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, testcase, mtm

I have a set of testcases in microsoft test manager. Now, the tester has to manually select each test case and run it. Is there a way in which I can link each step in the testcase to some program/script or to a function. 
eg. Consider my test case is to check the functionality of a DB.[Check sample testcase here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA4uT.png)

Is there some way through whic i can actually automate this. i.e. link the step to some program, which could of the following format for the first test case (in fig)

```
function updatedb(attributename){
//connect to db and change value`
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can link any unit test, coded UI test, or generic test to a test
>   case.

[Automate a test case in Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of a hack, but you could use the Test Recorder and have Visual Studio open or SQL Server Management Studio with your scripts and just click the "Run" button.  Your tester would have to have these open with your scripts, but it would work....

Or maybe open a MS-Dos prompt and record the typing and running of your script through there.